# Voronoi Flower characterization by extremal points

Tags: geometry, stochastic-geometry

The voronoi flower of a compact set $F\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ with respect to a point $x$ is given by
$$\mathcal{F}_x(F):=\bigcup_{y\in F}B_{\|y-x\|}(y).$$

I need to show that $\mathcal{F}_x(F)=\mathcal{F}_x(\text{conv}(F))$. This is a result that is generally known, but I haven't been able to find a proof of it.

So far, I've tried to prove it directly. For $F=\{a,b\}$ and $y=\alpha a+(1-\alpha)b$. Assuming $\|y-z\|<\|y-x\|$ and $\|a-z\|>\|a-x\|$ to show that $\|b-z\|<\|b-x\|$, but when I try to apply the triangle inequality I can't get there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This property is more or less established on page 716 of this document https://ahl.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/ahl.86.pdf